# How to replace all letters before first designated word?

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string like this:

```
$a="xxxGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS"; //may be more GOODS
```

How can I remove or replace all letters (`xxx` in this case, but not always) before the first `GOODS` only?

The result should be:

```
GOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS
```

or

```
some_other_lettersGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS
```

Comment: By using a regex like `^(.*?)GOODS` ;).

Comment: What are you having issues with? Tried something?

Comment: I have ever tried preg_replace("/^(.*?)GOODS/","",$a) before,but it replace all. 
Now i use preg_replace("/^(.*?)(GOODS)/","$2",$a), it works!

Comment: You don't need to first capture group. Take a look at my answer which should give you a little more information about what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

If by "letters" you mean characters, use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
echo strstr($a, 'GOODS');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that you could use.

```
$a="xxxGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS";
echo preg_replace('~^.*?(GOODS)~', '$1', $a) . "\n";
echo preg_replace('~^.*?(GOODS)~', 'some_other_letters$1', $a);
```

Output:

> GOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS
>   some_other_lettersGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS

`^` marks the start of the string
`.` is any character
`*` is a quantifier meaning zero or more of the previous character (in this case any character)
`?` stops the `*` from being greedy by matching the first occurrence of the next match `GOODS` (in this case).
`()` captures the value.
`$1` in the replace value is what was captured.
`~` are delimiters telling where the regex starts and ends. [Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) can be added after the closing delimiter to affect how the regex functions. For example if you also wanted `goods` to match you could make it case insensitive by adding an `i` after the closing `~`.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nD4iB1/1

Comment: As Casimir has demonstrated, regex is not necessary for this task.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one:

```
$a = "xxxGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS";
$b = str_replace('xxx', 'some_other_letters', $a);
echo $a;
echo '<br>';
echo $b;
```

OR

```
$a = 'xxxGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS';
echo preg_replace('/xxx/', 'some_other_letters', $a, 1);
```

Output:

```
xxxGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS
some_other_lettersGOODS yyyGOODS zzzGOODS
```

Comment: `str_replace` by default replaces all instances, though, and the question is specific about replacing just the first one. You need to pass in a fourth parameter to your call, to tell it to just replace the first instance.

Comment: As Casimir has demonstrated, regex is not necessary for this task.